# Add class to img if database value equals 1

Tags: php, html, mysql

I know this will probably be very simple, but I don't find a solution.

I am trying to add a class 'inactivelicence' to an object () when the database row 'glider' in table 'users' and where 'username = $u' equals '1'.

This is the code I have now (I only post the code that matters):

```
<?php
include_once("php_includes/check_login_status.php");

$u = "";
$glider = "";

if(isset($_GET["u"])){
    $u = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_GET['u']);
} else {
    header("location: index.html");
    exit(); 
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$u' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
$user_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    $glider= $row["glider"];

}

if($glider == "1"){
    echo "<script>$('#glider').addClass('inactivelicence')</script>"; 
}

?>

<div class="licences">

    <img id="glider" src="img/licences/icon_hc.png" > 

</div>
```

UPDATE:

I now have this code :

```
echo "<script>$(document).ready(function(){$('#glider').addClass('inactivelicence')})‌​;</script>";
```

But I still get an error on this line.. 
Error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in /home/a3318252/public_html/user.php on line 64

Comment: put the function after document ready.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($glider == "1"){
    echo "<script>$(document).ready(function(){$('#glider').addClass('inactivelicence')});</script>"; 
}
```

Comment: Then I get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in /home/a3318252/public_html/user.php on line 64

Comment: you missed a `.` in `$(document).ready()`..edited the answer..

Comment: Still gives me the same error (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in /home/a3318252/public_html/user.php on line 64) on this line: 
`echo "<script>$(document).ready(function(){$('#glider').addClass('inactivelicence')});</script>"; `